# Kotlin / Migration to View Binding

Tags: android, kotlin, binding

I was following YT video to make Quiz App, but in the end I got this error with binding:

- The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated.
- Please use this migration guide
  (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

But when I add *binding* for instance to *tv_name.text*, i do get error that *text* is  expecting Variable and everything the same with other binding parts.

**Libraries part**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import com.example.quizapp.databinding.ActivityResultBinding
```

**Code part**

```
    class ResultActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val binding by viewBinding(FragmentResultActivity::bind)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)

        // Hide the status bar.
        //window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

        val userName = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_NAME)
        binding.tv_name.text = userName

        val totalQuestions = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.TOTAL_QUESTIONS, 0)
        val correctAnswers = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.CORRECT_ANSWERS, 0)

        binding.tv_score.text = "Your Score is $correctAnswers out of $totalQuestions."

        binding.btn_finish.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@ResultActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the binding variable properly. Please use the below code:

```
class ResultActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityResultBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityResultBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Hide the status bar.
        //window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

        val userName = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_NAME)
        binding.tv_name.text = userName

        val totalQuestions = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.TOTAL_QUESTIONS, 0)
        val correctAnswers = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.CORRECT_ANSWERS, 0)

        binding.tv_score.text = "Your Score is $correctAnswers out of $totalQuestions."

        binding.btn_finish.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@ResultActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
        }
      }
   }
```

Since I do not have your resources with me available, I think you might have to change the naming of `ActivityResultBinding`. However, I am pretty sure this is it.

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately i do get same error and for 'ActivityResultBinding' i get Unresolved reference

Comment: Did you enable view binding?

Comment: @georkost both viewBinding and in buildFeatures enabled inside as well

Comment: Do you see any xxBinding class generated? If view binding is enabled then you should see some classes

Comment: I have fixed the issue with Binding class, but now it shows that **tv_name** is Unresolved reference as you see here 'binding.**tv_name**.text'  and to other binding objects as well

Comment: I have added libraries maybe i am missing something @georkost

Comment: I don't think it will be displayed as `tv_name` but as tvname or tvName. What do you see when you do a `binding.` does IDE autocomplete you with some options?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to let android know that you are using view binding. so go to "Gradle Scripts" folder and open app level `build.gradle(Module:nameOfProject)` file and inside `android` property add this:

```
android {

// ------ VIEW BINDING SETTING ------
// this creates the binding object
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding true
}
// after set up, click on  "Sync Now"
}
```

then in `MainActivity.kt`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Initialize binding object. if ActivityMainBinding is not ready in menu click "Build/Make project"
    private lateinit var binding:ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // view Bindig
//        binding default layout inflater
        binding= ActivityResultBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        // inflate the root views which is Linear Layout, we access with .root
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Set click listeners
      ....
}
```